# Angular/ng-select: Hide not bind items

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

how can I hide labels, which are not bind (with no label) in ng-select?
There is shown just empty box with "closing cross", but no label.

I would like to hide this box: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rnMl.png

I created some example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3wu26o?file=src%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.html

Maybe I could use some ng-class and display: none, but do not know the proper condition.

Thanks a lot for any advice.
Tomas

EDIT: I edited the example, hope it works correctly now ..

Comment: Maybe an easier solution would be to filter `this.item` on ngOnInit so that it only has valid items. e.g. `this.item = this.item.filter(x => this.codes.findIndex(y => y.id == x) !== -1);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have to preserve the item list. From the example, I need to keep id = 2 in the list, even if it has no code in the codes list. If I select 'eee' (id = 5), I need to send to db [1, 2, 3, 5]. If I remove 'aaa' (id = 1), I need to store [2, 3]. T.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution, which works for me:

```
div.ng-value.ng-star-inserted:has(span[ng-reflect-ng-item-label='']) {
   display: none;   
}
```